# Change the background Color of the cell according to $diff

Tags: php, ajax

I want to make a date filter page where one can filter the data stored in the database according to the range of dates.

I have a column "DIFF" which stores the time difference of Intime and Outtime. 
I want to change the background color of the cell according to the value stored in **$diff**. If it is less than 8 the red color else green.

I am not able to do this..
please help

```
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
  $cnt=1;     
  $output .= '  
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                 <th width="8%">Sr No.</th>  
                 <th width="18%">EMPLOYEE ID</th> 
                 <th width="30%">EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
                 <th width="15%">IN_TIME</th>  
                 <th width="15%">OUT_TIME</th>  
                 <th width="20%">DATE</th> 
                 <th width="20%">WORKING HOURS</th> 
            </tr>  
  ';  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
  {  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
       {  
                    $outtime = $row["outtime"];
                    $intime = $row["intime"];
                    $array1 = explode(':', $intime);
                    $array2 = explode(':', $outtime);

                    $minutes1 = ($array1[0] * 60.0 + $array1[1])/60;
                    $minutes2 = ($array2[0] * 60.0 + $array2[1])/60;

                    $diff = round(($minutes2 - $minutes1),1).' hrs';


            $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td align="center">'. $cnt .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["EmpId"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["FirstName"] . " " . 
                       $row["LastName"].'</td> 
                      <td align="center">'. $row["intime"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center"> '. $row["outtime"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["date"] .'</td> 
                      <td align="center" > '.$diff.' </td>
                 </tr>  
            ';  $cnt++;
       } 

  }  
  else  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td colspan="5">No Record Found</td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $output .= '</table>';  
  echo $output;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [background-color](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) property for td that you want to fill color.

Code should look like:

```
$output .= '<tr>  
                <td align="center">' . $cnt . '</td>  
                <td align="center">' . $row["EmpId"] . '</td>  
                <td align="center">' . $row["FirstName"] . " " . $row["LastName"] . '</td> 
                <td align="center">' . $row["intime"] . '</td>  
                <td align="center"> ' . $row["outtime"] . '</td>  
                <td align="center">' . $row["date"] . '</td>';
if ($diff < 8) {
    $output .= '<td align="center" style="background-color: #ff0000;"> ' . $diff . ' </td>';
} else {
    $output .= '<td align="center" style="background-color: #00ff00;"> ' . $diff . ' </td>';
}
$output .= '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried do a less than operation on the $diff variable?

You can try this, it sets the background color of the td depends on the $diff value.

change this part:
`<td align="center" > '.$diff.' </td>`

to this

`<td align="center" style="background-color: ($diff < 8) ? 'red' : 'green'" > '.$diff.' </td>`

Answer (score 0):

**check $diff is less then 8 or not**

use below code

```
<?php
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
  $cnt=1;     
  $output .= '  
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                 <th width="8%">Sr No.</th>  
                 <th width="18%">EMPLOYEE ID</th> 
                 <th width="30%">EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
                 <th width="15%">IN_TIME</th>  
                 <th width="15%">OUT_TIME</th>  
                 <th width="20%">DATE</th> 
                 <th width="20%">WORKING HOURS</th> 
            </tr>  
  ';  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
  {  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
       {  
                    $outtime = $row["outtime"];
                    $intime = $row["intime"];
                    $array1 = explode(':', $intime);
                    $array2 = explode(':', $outtime);

                    $minutes1 = ($array1[0] * 60.0 + $array1[1])/60;
                    $minutes2 = ($array2[0] * 60.0 + $array2[1])/60;

                    $diff = round(($minutes2 - $minutes1),1).' hrs';



            $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td align="center">'. $cnt .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["EmpId"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["FirstName"] . " " . 
                       $row["LastName"].'</td> 
                      <td align="center">'. $row["intime"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center"> '. $row["outtime"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["date"] .'</td> 
                      <td align="center" ';
                    if($diff  < 8)
                    {
                           $output .= 'bgcolor="red"';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $output .= 'bgcolor="green"';
                    }         
            $output .=  ' > '.$diff.' </td>
                 </tr>  
            ';  $cnt++;
       } 

  }  
  else  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td colspan="5">No Record Found</td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $output .= '</table>';  
  echo $output;  


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operators as

```
$diff = round(($minutes2 - $minutes1),1).' hrs';

            $colorCode = ($diff < 8)?"#ff0000":"#00ff00";
            $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td align="center">'. $cnt .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["EmpId"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["FirstName"] . " " . 
                       $row["LastName"].'</td> 
                      <td align="center">'. $row["intime"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center"> '. $row["outtime"] .'</td>  
                      <td align="center">'. $row["date"] .'</td> 
                      <td align="center" style="background-color:$colorCode"> '.$diff.' </td>
                 </tr>  
            ';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same by using php like :-

```
<td align="center"<?php if($diff<8){?> style="background-color: red; " <?php }else{?>style="background-color: green;"<?php } ?> > '.$diff.' </td>
```

or by using js too like :-

```
<td align="center" class="check" > '.$diff.' </td>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert($('.check').text());
 $(" tr > td.check").each(function(){
      if($(this).text()<8){
          $( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
      }else{
          $( this ).css( "background-color", "green" );
      }
    });
});
</script>
```